# Provide AppStore reviewers with Facebook test accounts

Tags: ios, appstore-approval, facebook-test-users

Our iOS app requires users to login using their Facebook account and we need to provide the AppStore reviewers with a test account(s).

- Can we take for granted that Apple have their own Facebook accounts that they use to test out apps that solely rely on Facebook for login?
- Do we need to set up a Facebook "test user" via their Test User API?

Grateful for any pointers from someone who did this.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: assume they have an account.

I think you're in a bit of a catch-22 here. It's probably against Facebooks terms of service to create a test account and hand those details to a third party... but, you're right, Apple *may* ask you for details.

However, in practice, they seem not to. One of my apps requires a login to a third-party website and I just put "you need an account" in the iTC notes section. I've been rejected once (since 2008) because I didn't specify a specific username/password. I explained why (see first paragraph) and it sailed through on the next attempt.

Having said that, apparently [Facebook allows a way of creating test accounts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17529/how-do-i-make-a-test-account-on-facebook). This is probably what you want to do if they insist.

Comment: Hi. I sent in a question to Apple support and they called me back and they said (to me surprise) that I need to create a fake account that the reviewers can use.

Comment: I just added a link to show how to create test accounts. (Wish the the site I have to interface with had the same feature!)

Answer (score 0):

For any app that requires a login you need to provide Apple with a guest/demo login account to test the app. So yes, give Apple a login/password to use.